# Переадресация обращения к домену

Tags: apache, nginx, apache2

Добрый день. Суть вопроса следующая.
Есть флеш приложение которое лежит на моем сервере. Оно обращается к домену - например site.ru, и получает от него данные.
Можно ли на уровне apache/nginx сделать так, чтобы это обращение шло к другому домену?

Comment: а это «флеш приложение» выполняется разве не в браузере клиента?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx легко проксирует запросы на любой адрес. Для этого существует директива [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass). Пример:

```
server {
   location {
      proxy_pass http://other.server.com;
   }
   location = /url.html {
      proxy_pass http://another.server.com;
   }
}
```